No Multicollinearity between highly Correlated IVs
Suppose I'm building a multiple regression model, with y as dependent variable and X1, X2,..., Xn as independent variables. I've come across cases when there is high correlation between 2 independent variables, say X1 & X2 correlation is 0.81, but there VIF is less than 3 for both these drivers.
Can someone please explain why this is possible? The common understanding is high correlation lead to multicollinearity as this post explains.
Please find an example below:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import variance_inflation_factor

# Seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(0)

# Generate 100 observations
n = 100

# Generate independent variables
X1 = np.random.normal(0, 1, n)
X2 = 0.8 * X1 + np.random.normal(0, 0.6, n)  # High correlation with X1

# Additional independent variable to balance the model
X3 = np.random.normal(0, 1, n)

# Dependent variable
Y = 2 + 3*X1 + 1.5*X2 + 2*X3 + np.random.normal(0, 1, n)

# Create a DataFrame
data = pd.DataFrame({'Y': Y, 'X1': X1, 'X2': X2, 'X3': X3})

# Fit the model
X = data[['X1', 'X2', 'X3']]
X = sm.add_constant(X)
model = sm.OLS(data['Y'], X).fit()
model.summary()


# Calculate VIF
vif_data = pd.DataFrame()
vif_data["feature"] = X.columns
vif_data["VIF"] = [variance_inflation_factor(X.values, i) for i in range(X.shape[1])]

vif_data


np.corrcoef(X1, X2)[0, 1]


Are there other predictors in the regression model?

Yes. Let me update my question to highlight this. I didn't specify any particular model, as I want to understand the intuitive reason why this can be possible. Thanks!

I suspect that the answer has to do with multi collinearity when there are several predictors. The more specific details you provide in the question, the more likely that you will get a useful answer.

This does seem odd.  It would be good to have more details of the model. Also, if you can, run condition indices.

Hi EdM I've added an example.

@Beta I just ran your example and it gives VIF > 3. Your original shouldn't be able to give VIF below $1/(1-0.81^2) = 2.9$. I'd assume you just misread a 2 as a 1?

I duplicated your model in R and, while all the VIFs were low, it also gave a warning  "Warning message:
In summary.lm(object, ...) :
essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable"

I updated the answer with the results. VIF is less than 5, so there is no multicollinearity. So, the question is why in high correlated drivers, we are observing low multicollinearity?

There is multicollinearity, but it just doesn't rise to the level that most would consider problematic.
In an ordinary least squares model, the variance inflation factor (VIF) for predictor i is
$$ \mathrm{VIF}_i = \frac{1}{1-R^2_i},$$
where $R_i^2$ is the multiple $R^2$ (coefficient of determination) for a linear model of predictor $i$ against all of the other predictors. The outcome variable isn't even considered.
Consider an even simpler situation than what you propose, with only X1 and X2 as predictors. Then the coefficient of determination for either against the other is the square of their correlation coefficient.(Lukas Lohse made a related point in a comment.)
A correlation coefficient of 0.8 might seem large, but its square is only 0.64, so the VIF is only about 2.8. For a 2-predictor model you need a correlation greater than about 0.9 to have a VIF greater than 5, or greater than about 0.95 for a VIF greater than 10.
